# In Swift, the navigation Bar dissappear and never comes back

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to push a new view controller from the current controller with the push of a button. But as soon as the new controller is presented, the navigation bar from the top disappear and I have tried numerous ways but just cant seem to get it back.

I am doing all my code programmatically without any use of the Interface Builder.

I have tried the list of below codes but none of them worked.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "backimg"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(backTapped))

    let webV:UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
    webV.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://*****************.com")! as URL) as URLRequest)
    webV.delegate = self;
    self.view.addSubview(webV)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
}

@objc func backTapped(_ sender: Any){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I am trying to push the view controller from the target function of the button as follows :

```
  @objc func parkingTimerTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let pp = ParkingModeScheduleView()

    self.present(pp, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("Parking Timer Tapped")
 }
```

I have also already tried to push the view controller using the command below :

```
  self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pp, animated: true)
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: have you checked your navigation controller is not nil?

Comment: i dont know how to check that but the navigation controller is displayed on all the other screens and controllers that i made a while ago. recently i came to add another and ran into this issue. If is works and show on all other views, then it cant be nil ?! or can it?

Comment: @WasimMalek i just tried to print it and yes it is indeed NIL. but how is it possible if it is not on all other controllers? How can i fix it? 

Thanks so much for pointing it out though.

Comment: you need to add this view controller in navigation controller. if you are using storyboard then select view controller and embed in navigation controller.

Comment: no i am not using storyboard

Comment: Then you need to add your parkingModeScheduleview in UINavigation. let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pp) and then present navigation instead of pp.

Comment: this worked, i cant believe it was that simple. Thanks so much pal i appreciate it. Post your comment as the answer so i can accept it <3 <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add your parkingModeScheduleview in UINavigation controller like this

```
@objc func parkingTimerTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let pp = ParkingModeScheduleView()
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: pp)
    self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
    print("Parking Timer Tapped")
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `self.present(pp, animated: true, completion: nil)` shows your new view controller as modal so it is not part of the navigation stack at all and that's why there is no navigation bar.

I'd recommend to try with `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pp, animated: true)` but first check if `self.navigationController` is not `nil` for some reason. Also remove all navigation bar hidden related methods from your `ParkingModeScheduleView`

Comment: didnt work brother, i still appreciate your time and effort